# Remote debug a site? JSON issue with IE8

Tags: html, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

The scenario is that the website works wonderfully on all machines except the ones where the client works. It's in Africa and I've no hope of getting access to it. He has limited IT knowledge and we don't know a great deal about the companies net policies.

I know that he is using IE8 with the doc mode being 8 as well, I suspected it was running in 7 because of some CSS issues but apparently not.

I use a JSON file and Ajax query to populate an important part of the site. It works well in all main browsers. I've used Dev mode and tried IE7 and IE8 and it still works.

However, his machine doesn't load anything, I output messages into the console and when he checked (confirmed via screen dump) there was emptiness.

What is love is either a way or means of debugging it from here, full details about his machine or some explanation as to why the json can't be read.

If anyone is using IE8 perhaps you could have a peek- it's kingpetroleum.co.uk/conversion.php

The drop down should populate the form web selected. 
Thanks for any help.

Edit: there's a redirect on the index page that goes to the old site. Please use the /conversion.php if you check it out

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find kingpeteoleum.co.uk

Comment: Sorry. It's kingpetroleum.co.uk

Comment: I just visited your site and I'm not seeing any options visible - it's in the DOM (after inspecting) but there is no text in the `<option>` tags. i.e. `<option class="" id="a" value="a"></option>` (this was on Chrome)

Comment: @SuviVignarajah - thanks for taking the time to check.  It should be empty until an option is selected from the menu.  Was this what you did?

Comment: Ah ok, I see - I wasn't aware of that. But ye, I see the options populated now. Hmm..regarding your issue though - if this is related to JSON and IE8 my suggestion would be to make sure you include the [JSON3 polyfill](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) in your page.

Comment: @SuviVignarajah.  Sorry, I should've explained further.  The polyfill you mentioned.  Should it just be included as you would a script file? I came across this post : http://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-webshims-polyfill/ - would you recommend this method?

Comment: I've never actually used webshims polyfill but that does seem like one approach you can take. You should just be aware that even though you can specify which feature to polyfill, the script that's loaded still carries the weight of polyfills for all features - so performance-wise this might not be optimal, if you're only going to be polyfilling one feature. See answer below for how to implement JSON-3 polyfill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to add a polyfill for the JSON object which is not supported on older browsers. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility) for more info on browser compatibility of the JSON object. They mention that it should be compatible for IE8, but this is not always the case and if the user is running IE8 in compatibility-mode it won't work either.

You should include the polyfill script file before you load your other scripts, I recommend doing it in conditional comments:

```
<head>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="/path/to/json3.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

This would only load the polyfill for IE8 and below.

Comment: Thanks Suvi, I'll try it now, test and let you know.