# IE8 - "is null or not an object" error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the HTML:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><div id="resultCount">n.v.</div></td>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
 function processResultCount(data) {
    $("#resultCount").html(formatNumber(data.resultCount, "."));
    $("#resultCount2").html(formatNumber(data.resultCount, "."));
    for (property in data) {
        var value = data[property];
        $("#" + property).html(formatNumber(value, "."));
    }

function formatNumber(nStr, delimiter) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
 x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;    
.....
......
```

In IE8, I get the error: "resultCount is null or not an object"

Comment: How is `data` object populated ?

Comment: What is the runtime value of `data` when this error happens?  Clearly it doesn't have a `resultCount` member on it.

Comment: Maybe you're triggering your function before page gets loaded completely.

Comment: Where/when/how do you call the function processResultCount?

Comment: See here for JSON objects and compatible browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538757/remote-debug-a-site-json-issue-with-ie8/18542785#18542785

Answer (score 0):

I call the function processResultCount here:

```
var jsonFormOptions = {
    // dataType identifies the expected content type of the server response
    dataType: 'json',
    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response
    // has been received
    success: processResultCount(),
    error: handleResultCountError,
    // will be overridden in setupExtSearchFormBindings()
    url: jsonFormUrl,
    type: 'get'
}
```